# WPBakery Page Builder Image grid load more with ajax

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I am using **WPBakery Page Builder** for my wordpress site.
For images i am using **Image Grid** I want a scenario like First display 6 images
and when user clicks on **Load More** It will load 6 images more. I want that with AJAX. **WPBakery Page Builder** provides pagination functionality but how can i achieve with AJAX ??

Comment: what are you tried ?

Comment: I tried finding hooks or something ... but nothing found